# Js - check if nested values of object are the same

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these nested objects. How can I check if the group_id are all the same?

```
console.log(getData);

{…}
    "$": function g()​
    0: {…}
        DT_RowId: "row_1"
        groups: Object { group_id: 2, … }
    1: {…}
        DT_RowId: "row_2"
        groups: Object { group_id: 2, … }
    2: {…}
        DT_RowId: "row_3"
        groups: Object { group_id: 2, … }
    3: {…}
        DT_RowId: "row_4"
        groups: Object { group_id: 2, … }
```

A .each() provides me:  ​​

```
$.each( getData, function ( id, val ) {
    console.log(val.groups.group_id);
});

2
2
2
2
```

Comment: If `getData` is an array, you can use  [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to return true/false if every item in an array meets a given condition.

Comment: What is `getData`? Seems like it is a jQuery object?? Hard to answer without knowing what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unclear what the data exactly is. If it is in array format `every()` is what you need, compare it to the first index value

```js
var objData = [
  { groups: { group_id: 2 } },
  { groups: { group_id: 2 } },
  { groups: { group_id: 2 } },
  { groups: { group_id: 2 } },
  { groups: { group_id: 2 } },
]

var allMatch = objData.every((n, i, a) => n.groups.group_id===a[0].groups.group_id)

console.log(allMatch)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It seems like it might be an object in that case simple conversion can make it into an array

```js
var objData = {
  '$': {},
  0: { groups: { group_id: 2 } },
  1: { groups: { group_id: 2 } },
  2: { groups: { group_id: 2 } },
  3: { groups: { group_id: 2 } },
  4: { groups: { group_id: 2 } },
}

var allMatch = Object.values(objData)
  .filter(o => o.groups)
  .every((n, i, a) =>
    n.groups.group_id === a[0].groups.group_id
  )

console.log(allMatch)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of that being nested objects you could do something like:
`Object.values(getData).map(val => val.groupId).every((groupId, i, arr) => groupId === arr[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

if `getData` is an object

```
  Object.keys(getData).every(key => getData[key].group_id === getData[0].group_id)
```

We first get the keys of the `getData` object container, and then we use the array of keys to access the `getData` object to check each `obj.group_id`

if `getData` is an array containing objects

```
  getData.every(obj => getData[obj].group_id === getData[0].group_id)
```

Similar to the above, except we can directly iterate over the array of objects

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't know if group_id equals 2 ... I need to check if the are all the same ...

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that all the items have the same group id, this ensures that all items have the id of 2

Comment: Ah I misread the question, apologies. @PhilippM do you know what ID you'd like to check for? I've updated it to just make sure that it matches the first group's `group_id`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` to iterate though the object and use `every` to test all values satisfy the condition.

```js
const nestedObj = {
    0: {
        DT_RowId: "row_1",
        groups: { group_id: 2}
    },
    1: {
        DT_RowId: "row_2",
        groups: { group_id: 2}
    },
    2: {
        DT_RowId: "row_3",
        groups: { group_id: 2}
    },
    3: {
        DT_RowId: "row_4",
        groups: { group_id: 2}
    }    

}

const GROUP_ID = nestedObj[0].groups.group_id;
const isGroupIdSame = Object.keys(nestedObj).every(key => nestedObj[key].groups.group_id === GROUP_ID);

console.log(isGroupIdSame)
```